# Converting non equidistant point data to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point, csv, interpolation

I have a csv file in which first column is longitude, second is latitude and third is temperature. However, the points are not at all equidistant i.e. for each pair of lat-lon I have a value. I want to convert it to 2D raster.

I tried with matlab (triangulation and griddata interpolation), but it was giving me 3D raster (surface).

Also, in ArcGIS I tried using XY data as x-lon, y-lat and z-temp but it was not showing georeferenced points. Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you'll need to accomplish two major steps, which are:

- (i) import your data on ArcGIS and set an appropriate coordinate reference system:

[Layers with same coordinate system should align/overlap but do not?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-but-do-not/54601#54601)

- (ii) perform the interpolation and output to a raster:

[Converting points to raster in ArcGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14593/converting-points-to-cells-using-arcgis-desktop/14594#14594)

---

For more info about ArcGIS interpolation tools, see [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/an-overview-of-the-interpolation-tools.htm).